# Show that there exists a number $d_1$ such that $a_1 x^m \geq x^2-d_1$ for all x

Tags: real-analysis

Here m is even and greater than 2 and $a_1$ is some positive number. I tried many solutions but just cannot get the answer.

Comment: Show there exists $K$ so that if $|x|>K$ then $a_1x^m\ge x^2$. Now consider the function $a_1x^m-x^2$ restricted to $[-K,K]$...

Comment: what is the condition on $d_1$ ?

Comment: $d_1$ can be any number but it has to hold for all x. So I think $d_1$ can change with m and a1 if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $d_1$ must be greater than $x^2—a_1x^m$, you should try to find the maximum of this expression.